# Does PhoneGap host html pages on the phone or have to connect to the server?

Tags: cordova

I'm trying out PhoneGap in Visual Studio. If I create an app and allow someone to install it, what happens if they try to launch it when they don't have internet connectivity? Ideally, I'd like the app to still display something to the user even if the server is unavailable. Are the web pages hosted locally on the phone and connect to the server via JavaScript and web services? Or are the pages hosted on a web server which the phone needs to have access to for the app to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhoneGap is a technology that transforms web apps into native apps. Nothing runs on a server unless you explicitly define it that way.

It packages HTML/JavaScript/CSS into local resources that are loaded when needed by the native wrappers.

Comment: OK, that's good. I was confused because I saw ASP.NET Development server launching when I started debugging, but I figured out that was because of a WCF REST service project I added - not the PhoneGap project.